# Semantic Annotation in text with curlie.org

Tags: annotation

I came across curlie.org (previously known as the dmoz taxonomy) and I'm interested to see how I could best start tagging a given text, with concepts from that taxonomy:

- Are there any tools out there that do semantic annotation based on a taxonomy (I couldn't find any)
- How would one go about making such a semantic annotation process

I know this question might be a large to answer in a short reply, but any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add some extra info about the kind of annotations you would like to perform? Are you thinking about a specific domain? Do you need them to train a ML model or perform other analysis?

Comment: Hi @EdoardoGuerriero, we were thinking in general about http://curlie.org/ annotations, so semantic concepts. Preferably we can use this in a general way, if we have to we'd have to train a certain domain? i.e. "Politics"? So it's not about classification, but really about identifying concepts in a text, based on something like curlie.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm still not sure about what you consider to be an annotation on curlie.org. What I understood, you'll correct me if I'm wrong, is that you would like to annotate some text, more specifically you would like to annotate/identify concepts, and you would like to follow the structure on curlie.

From what I see, curlie doesn't contain any annotation, it's more like a website ontology, which has at the bottom real url and as hypernyms domain-specific topics and then at the top level broad topics. So the only thing you might consider an annotation, at document level, i.e. a single label for a whole website, is the domain-specific topic.

If you want to create an ontology similar to curlie, [Protege](https://protege.stanford.edu) could be a good choice. Also, if you're interested in retrieving some general taxonomy information for a word, you probably want to look at some lexical databased like [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu) or [ConceptNet](http://conceptnet.io).

If this is not what you want and you're interested in making your own annotations at word level, e.g. "I bought an iPhone[*object*]" then probably the taxonomy of curlie is too generic and you will definitely need to narrow down the scope of your annotations. Take a look at some literature of NLP tasks like *Named entity recognition*, it's plenty of papers. Also, if you will go down this road (creating your own annotations) a good tool is [Prodigy](https://prodi.gy). Consider that even at word level, annotations can defined at several levels for each document. For example, in opinion mining usually people are interested in annotating not only a chunk of words representing an opinion, but also other aspects like the target of the opinion, e.g. "[This [GPS]$_{target}$ really sucks]$_{opinion}$, it never works!".
But in my experience people stop at max 3 layers of annotations, and it truly depends on the purpose for which the annotations are made in the first place.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the links to Word/ConceptNet, I didn't know that existed. I am indeed wondering what I need to do in order to annotate texts as you described in your iPhone example: [SpaceX](wiki:/SpaceX) is a company that build [space rockets](curlie.org/Space_Rocket). Do I understand it correctly this could be accomplished by using NER and letting Word/ConceptNet link those entities? Using ConceptNet for more general high level concepts, and then use dbpedia, curlie, ... for more specific ones?